# Points on a webmap openlayers

Tags: html, vector, arcgis, openlayers-3, shapefile

I have very little experience in GIS. I am working on a project were I need to put around 120 coordinate points on a web map using openlayers 3. There are also attributes associated with these points. I added the points from a csv into arcGis. I turned them into a shapefile. I also have a web map with a satellite image of the area. It works and opens in a browser.Now what do I do? Can someone point me in the right direction. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shapefile can be converted into a GeoJSON (e.g. with an [online service](http://ogre.adc4gis.com) or [QGIS](http://qgis.org). The GeoJSON can then directly be consumed by OpenLayers:

```js
map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: 'path/to/your.geojson'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload your shapefile on a server in order to publish it on your map via web protocols like Web Map Service (WMS) or Web Features Service (WFS).

Take a look [at the OpenGeo Suite](http://boundlessgeo.com/products/), it should get you started. You can install GeoServer locally to develop and test your application, and then migrate it all on your web server.

Another option would be to use QGIS GeoExplorer to directly have a working interface with differents options.